# Script to export rows to txt-file based on value in column

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a simple script to export rows based on values in a specific cell. Has found this script (maybe it could be done a bit simpler?) but need help to filter my txt output, so that only rows with an "x" in column B is exported.

```
Sub Export()
'Declaring variables
Dim sLine As String
Dim sFName As String
Dim intFNumber As Integer
Dim lCounter As Long
Dim lLastRow As Long

'Just showing where the input data are
Worksheets("mysheet").Activate
Range("A9").Select

'Find the last row that contains data
With Worksheets("mysheet")
    lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

'Setting the name and the path of text file based on workbook path
sFName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\txtfile.txt"

'Get an unused file number
intFNumber = FreeFile

'Create a new file (or overwrite an existing one)
Open sFName For Output As #intFNumber

    'Choose first row to export
    For lCounter = 2 To lLastRow

        'Read specific data from the worksheet
        With Worksheets("mysheet")
            sLine = .Cells(lCounter, 1)
        End With

        'Write data to file if there is an x in column B (I just need column A to be written  what should ????? be?)
        If ?????? = "x" Then
            Print #intFNumber, sLine
        End If

    'Continue looping until the last row
    Next lCounter

'Close file
Close #intFNumber           
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
If Worksheets("mysheet").cells(lCounter, 2) = "x" Then 'the 2 in this line refers to the column B
    Print #intFNumber, sLine
End If
```

This will write the contents of Column A if Column B has an x in it.

Comment: Thanks a lot  (again:-)